# Запустить слейв из Jenkins используя Groovy DSL и AWS EC2 plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Используется [AWS EC2 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin).
Нужно сделать "provision slave" прямо из дженкинс джоби, используя Groovy DSL.

Comment: @Владимир с дженкинсом не всегда получается код выкладывать, там его может и не быть )

Comment: @ Nick Volynkin Спасибо понял.